# cmake target created with ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET() generated multiple times in parallel mode

Tags: cmake, parallel-processing, code-generation, parallel-builds

I have project name [libtld](https://snapwebsites.org/project/libtld) where I first create a tool¹:

```
project(tld_parser)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ../tools/tldc.cpp

    tld_compiler.cpp
    tld_file.cpp
    tld_strings.c
)
```

Then I use that tool to generate the `tld_data.c` file, which is a table with all the TLDs (in my newer version of the library, this is a copy of the RIFF/TLDS binary file which is to be compiled internally as a fallback). Here is the `add_custom_command()` I use to generate said file:

```
project(tld_data)
set(TLD_DATA_C ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tld_data.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE TLD_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/tlds/*.ini)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${TLD_DATA_C}
    COMMAND "tld_parser"
                "--source"
                    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/conf/tlds"
                "--verify"
                "--output-json"
                    "--include-offsets"
                "--c-file"
                    "${TLD_DATA_C}"
                "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tlds.tld"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY tld_parser
    DEPENDS ${TLD_FILES}
)
add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME} ALL DEPENDS ${TLD_DATA_C})
define_property(SOURCE
    PROPERTY GENERATED
    BRIEF_DOCS "The tld_data.c file is a table of all the TLDs defined in conf/tlds/... .ini files."
    FULL_DOCS "In the new version, the tld_data.c is always generated on the fly since it can be done with just C/C++."
)
```

Next I want to generate the tld dynamic and static libraries.

```
set(LIBTLD_SOURCES
    tld.cpp
    tld_compiler.cpp
    ${TLD_DATA_C}
    tld_domain_to_lowercase.c
    tld_emails.cpp
    tld_file.cpp
    tld_object.cpp
    tld_strings.c
)

##
## TLD library
##
project(tld)
configure_file(
    tld.h.in
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tld.h
)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
    ${LIBTLD_SOURCES}
)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${LIBTLD_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LIBTLD_VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${LIBTLD_VERSION_MAJOR}
)
install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    COMPONENT runtime
)
install(
    FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/tld.h
    DESTINATION include
    COMPONENT development
)

##
## TLD static library
##
project(tld_static)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
    ${LIBTLD_SOURCES}
)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    tld
)
# We need the -fPIC to use this library as extension of PHP, etc.
set_target_properties(tld_static PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fPIC)

install(
    TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    COMPONENT development
)
```

I added the `add_dependencies()` to the `tld_static` project to depend on `tld` thinking that would help my case, but I still see two run of the `tld_parser`...

I also had a test that directly includes the `tld_data.c` file (that way I can directly verify that the `tld()` function returns what I would expect from the exact source data).

Adding the `add_dependencies()` to the test worked as expected. Instead of getting the `tld_data.c` file created three times, now it's only twice.

```
project(tld_internal_test)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    tld_internal_test.cpp
)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    tld
)
add_test(
    NAME ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

By killing the parallel build feature, it works as expected, however, there should be no good reasons for me to do that (see [this cmake question](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-October/024491.html) for reference).

What I'm wondering, though, is:

**How do you debug such an issue?**

cmake's Makefile's are enormous, so reading those is quite a killer. If I knew what to search for, I suppose I could at least look at specific targets instead of trying to understand all that's happening in there (most of which has nothing to do with my issue).

---

¹ The [code is in a branch](https://github.com/m2osw/libtld/tree/SNAP-737-remove-qt-dependency) at the moment. I'm hoping to have it all wrapped up soon at which point it will replace the main branch. The `tld()` function interface will not have changed very much. The implementation, however, will be quite different, more flexible, dynamically updatable.

Comment: Instead of `add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME} ALL DEPENDS ${TLD_DATA_C})` try `add_library(.... OBJECT)` and linking with it. maybe try a static lbrary, but dunno how to include it in shared library. `cmake's Makefile'` Yes, so if you want to debug, you debug the build system. But anyway, move to Ninja - it's faster, and it can build `ninja -t browse` a dependency graph for you. `COMMAND "tld_parser"` use `$<TARGET_FILE:tld_patrser>`. Are you 100% sure, that `tld_parser` does not change modification times of any other file? Could be it's opening any of `TLD_FILES` files for modification.

Comment: https://github.com/m2osw/libtld/blob/SNAP-737-remove-qt-dependency/libtld/tld_compiler.cpp#L1402 -- here? It's opening read/write, am I right? Are modification times of `TLD_FILES` getting updated?

Comment: It is `tld_data` target which creates the file `tld_data.c`. So you libraries should depends (via `add_dependencies`) from that target, not from the `tld` one. Note also to that description for [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html): Do not list the output in more than one independent target that may build in parallel or the two instances of the rule may conflict (instead use the `add_custom_target()` command to drive the command and make the other targets depend on that one).

Comment: @KamilCuk I verified with `stat <some .ini file>` and clearly it doesn't change the modification time (or any time if that matter). The default mode when opening an input stream is `ios_base::in`, (see [basic_istream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream))

Comment: @KamilCuk Ah! Good catch! :-) Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @Tsyvarev It works using tld_data instead of tld (or as I tried before tld_data.c) in the add_dependencies() works! Now I only see one run of tld_parser and when I re-run make, it does not rebuild every time. Perfect! If you'd like to write an answer, I'll mark it as the valid answer.